# How to plot a histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some problems plotting a histogram.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
2012-06-20 23:00:00     600
2014-07-01 03:26:00   1,000
2013-09-30 04:00:00   1,000
2013-09-17 03:59:00     400
2015-02-12 18:41:20     100
2015-03-12 07:53:07     100
2015-03-01 04:59:00     200
2015-02-16 22:22:31   1,000
2015-03-01 03:00:00   1,000
2015-01-12 06:00:00      10
2015-03-03 04:59:00     100
2014-06-21 18:00:38     500
```

When I try to plot a histogram, I apply:

```
df['cars'].hist(bins=50)
```

However, it only returns

```
Out: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x19801be10
```

Without any plot?

Thanks for help!

**Solved:** %matplotlib inline solved the problem (iPython Notebook)

But now it looks like this:

[image: Plot]

df.describe() returns

```
          location      cars
count     65,600        65,600       
mean      3,373,467     16,000
std       5,516,816     120,000
min       2,351,479     0
25%       2,397,816     1,400
50%       2,452,537     4,500
75%       2,485,749     11,200
max       99,999,999    18,000,000
```

**Solved #2:** I checked the db and indeed, there's a high maximum value that causes the plot to look like that. Thank you for your support!

Comment: How are you running this? If in ipython try adding `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Please edit your comment into the question, the formatting gets lost in the comments

Comment: Okay. Inline works :). But now it looks like this: [http://postimg.org/image/c3j4yycan/](http://postimg.org/image/c3j4yycan/)

Comment: Again post the image into your question don't add as a comment

Comment: Please post the output from `df.info()` as I can plot your code fine

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'info'

Comment: `df.info()` not `df['cars'].info()` unless your df is in fact a series

Comment: You can do `df.describe()` also

Comment: Just updated. df.info() doesn't output anything btw.

Comment: Can't reproduce, can you post raw input data or a link to your data file and all the code to load it into a df

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the whole dataset. But a sample of df.['cars'] looks like this: http://pastebin.com/GeUqr1ra

Comment: Well I can plot your data fine, can you add to your post the numpy and pandas versions

Comment: I'm using Anaconda  1.0.0 with Python 2.7.9.final.0. That's all I can say. Should be numpy 1.9.2 and pandas 0.15.2 according to changelog.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to plot the total count of projects and not sort it into buckets on the y-axis..?

Comment: it may be a bug, can you upgrade pandas? also what does `df.plot(kind='hist', bins=50)` show

Comment: I don't really understand what should be wrong? You just have a very large maximum value, so for this reason all other values fall into one bin, and the histogram looks a bit 'off'.

Comment: You're right. I checked the db and indeed, there's a high maximum value. Thank you for your support!